# Simple script with infinite loop slows down the computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, infinite-loop, win32gui

```
import win32gui
import pyautogui
import winsound

def get_pixel_colour(i_x, i_y):
    i_desktop_window_id = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    i_desktop_window_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(i_desktop_window_id)
    long_colour = win32gui.GetPixel(i_desktop_window_dc, i_x, i_y)
    i_colour = int(long_colour)
    return (i_colour & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 8) & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 16) & 0xff)

def is_top_free(x, y):
    if all(i in range(35,46) for i in get_pixel_colour(x+258, y+108) and get_pixel_colour(x+283, y+108) and get_pixel_colour(x+283, y+139) and get_pixel_colour(x+258, y+139)) and all(i in range(80, 90) for i in get_pixel_colour(x+264, y+131)):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def is_bottom_free(x, y):
    if all(i in range(35, 46) for i in get_pixel_colour(x+256, y+788) and get_pixel_colour(x+286, y+788) and get_pixel_colour(x+256, y+820) and get_pixel_colour(x+286, y+820)) and all(i in range(80, 90) for i in get_pixel_colour(x+264, y+808)):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def get_top_seat(x, y):
    current = pyautogui.position()
    pyautogui.click(x+267, y+126)
    pyautogui.moveTo(current[0], current[1])
    winsound.Beep(500, 500)

def get_bottom_seat(x, y):
    current = pyautogui.position()
    pyautogui.click(x+267, y+802)
    pyautogui.moveTo(current[0], current[1])
    winsound.Beep(500, 500)

def callback(hwnd, extra):
    rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    x = rect[0]
    y = rect[1]
    w = rect[2] - x
    h = rect[3] - y
    if win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) in accounts:
        if is_top_free(x, y):
            get_top_seat(x, y)
        elif is_bottom_free(x, y):
            get_bottom_seat(x,y)

accounts = ['3948700830', '3949029392', '3949074503', '3949131493', '3949174547', '3949206036']

try:
    while True:
        win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, None)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('End')
```

This script looks for a button and clicks it when possible.

Computer works slower and slower while running this script. I guess some variables are being overwritten without deleting from memory. I tried adding some sleep to the loop but it didn't solve the problem - it slows down slower but still regularly. Do you have any ideas what might cause it?

Comment: This isn't directly related to your problem, but I don't think your conditionals starting with `if all` will work properly. You can't chain together multiple `get_pixel_colour` calls and get `for i in...` to iterate over them all. Consider: if you do `(11,12,13) and (4,5,6)` in the interactive prompt, the result is `(4,5,6)`, rather than `(11,12,13,4,5,6)`.

Comment: Hmm, based on the docs of [`GetWindowDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowdc) you should call `ReleaseDC` when done using it. I don't see one, which might be the problem. I would also consider optimizing fetching pixel colour. Ideally for each window, you'd call `GetWindowDC` once, extract all the pixels values you need and then release it. (Also, I'd really consider rewriting the `if` condition in `is_bottom_free` and `is_top_free` ... this is nasty to parse to say the least)

Comment: They work properly. It finds the button when it appears and click on it. The problem is only efficiency.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I'll check it.

Comment: Let me clarify. When I say they won't work properly, I don't mean that the program will crash or anything. I mean that the code will do fewer checks than it's supposed to, and occasionally say that a window matches when it's not supposed to. Essentially your first conditional is checking only the result of `get_pixel_colour(x+258, y+139)`, and completely ignoring all the calls preceding it.

Answer (score 0):

This helped in resolving the problem:

```
def get_pixel_colour(i_x, i_y):
    i_desktop_window_id = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    i_desktop_window_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(i_desktop_window_id)
    long_colour = win32gui.GetPixel(i_desktop_window_dc, i_x, i_y)
    i_colour = int(long_colour)
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(i_desktop_window_id, i_desktop_window_dc)
    return (i_colour & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 8) & 0xff), ((i_colour >> 16) & 0xff)
```

Thank you Dan Mašek! It was all about realising device context.